# How to go about creating a user authentication system for a Java web app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I am trying to build a user authentication system for my Java web application, a basic inventory management system. I want to use AWS Cognito to keep track of all user information, and I am planning to deploy this app to Elastic Beanstalk, where it will also use some AWS database storage (DynamoDB or RDS, to be determined) to store the inventory data. This is my first Java web application so I am having a bit of a hard time understanding how the different technologies can work together.

After doing some research on building a user authentication system for a Java web app, it seems that [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) would be a great framework to use as it would eliminate a lot of the grunt work with building a login system. However, pretty much every guide I have come across for a Spring MVC login system in Java requires Gradle or Maven. (I would be using Maven since I'm more familiar with it.) This is fine for when I'm running my project locally, but I'm concerned about how this will work when I want to upload my project to Elastic Beanstalk. It seems that the only way to deploy a a Java application from Maven to Elastic Beanstalk is with a [open source project called Beanstalker](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploying-java-applications-on-elastic-beanstalk-from-maven/), and I'm worried that if I develop my application using Spring MVC and Maven, when it comes time to put my project on Elastic Beanstalk I won't understand how to use this tool/it won't work properly.

So here are my main questions:

1. Would Spring MVC be a good tool to use in building my user authentication system? Is there a different framework I should look into?
2. Does using Spring MVC absolutely require the use of Gradle or Maven, or is there a way to build a user auth system with Spring MVC without it?
3. If I do use Spring MVC to build the auth system with Maven dependencies, will I have a hard time deploying it to Elastic Beanstalk, or am I overthinking it?

Thanks for any information, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sure
2. Spring MVC does not require a specific dependency management tool
3. No more difficult than deploying any other Java app to EB

Note, you dont have to deploy using Maven just because you use Maven for dependency management. You would typically use the official Elastic Beanstalk [command line tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) to deploy your application.